# ASP.NET MVC 5 Action strange error(?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-mvc-5

I've a very simple site, I'm new in ASP.NET MVC. In the Account controller I've Login and Logout. The Login works great even the http post, the user can log in, I'm adding the userId to the session:

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    //Login process ...

    Session.Add("TrakIOLoggedUser", userName);
}
```

In the Logout I'm removing this Session variable:

```
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    if (Session["TrakIOLoggedUser"] != null) Session.Remove("TrakIOLoggedUser");
}
```

And now the strange thing: when I leave the site without any interaction when I click the Logout link it just redirects to the Index, to the default action, it seems that the action doesn't exists in the controller.
when I rename the action to anything else, for example Logoff and after Login in a short time I click Logout link, it calls the Logoff, everything is ok, but after Login again when I leave it alone for a few minutes (I think the Session expires) it doesn't work, like before when it called Logout.

The breakpoint doesn't hit, it redirects me again to the default action. After this I can rename it to Logoff or Logout, nothing works, even after Visual Studio and Windows restart. Like it's remember for that names :D :D

If I give a new name, it works again if I don't leave it alone. What the f... is that? Any other action which doesn't interacts with the Session works great anytime...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't your `Logout` method return any `ActionResult`? I can't see it in your code.

Comment: There was a RedirectToActionPermanent("Index"); as in the Login too... It seems that Permanent redirection causes not the session expires.
I'm testing with RedirectToAction and it works